# Android java : How to create folder inside android devices?

Tags: android

I was developing an app and needed to create a folder inside SD card when button is onClick.
I have no idea how to do it. Anyone can help ? Please.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_date_select);
    edit_date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_date);
    edit_date.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    btn_setDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_setDate);
   btn_setDate.setOnClickListener(this);
    updateDate();

    btn_cFolder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cFolder);
     btn_cFolder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) 
            {
             Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
             File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/wahaha");
             boolean success = true;
             if (!folder.exists()) {
                 success = folder.mkdir();
             }
             if (success) {
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have successfully created." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
             } else {
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have Failed to create." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
             }
            }
   });

}
```

I'm beginner of android develop.
okay i now have doing many of research and i found out the folder are able to see on the android device. But once i plugged into PC . still not able to see. Any suggestion see the folder on PC? 
And by the way why it save to internal storage ?

Comment: this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853472/creating-a-directory-in-sdcard-fails

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make directory in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280176/make-directory-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 step:

1. To get sd card is mounted at `/sdcard` or any other location by using this way:

   ```
   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
   ```
2. You have to take uses-permission entry in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   ```
3. If directory already exists, then mkdir return false. Try creatinng new directory if it not exist:

   ```
   File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/map");
   boolean success = true;
   if (!folder.exists()) {
       success = folder.mkdir();
   }
   if (success) {
       // Do something on success
   } else {
       // Do something else on failure 
   }
   ```

Comment: when click the button it toast success but when i check the sd card doesnt see the folder.

Comment: You give user permision in AndroidManiferst.xml

Comment: still doesnt see the folder . so weird

Comment: hey thanks you so much by giving this answer =)
I found out the folder are able to see on the android device. But once I plugged into PC . still not able to see and it saved to internal storage I thought save to SD card?

Comment: ohh its save to internal storage ? how? we take a external storage permission so internal storage how to saved. double check

Comment: so weird = = all created at internal storage = =

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  File dir = new File( "dir_name");
  dir.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
File f2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Folder");   
f2.mkdirs();
```

And also you have to add write permission in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// create a File object for the parent directory
File nameofDirectory = new File("/sdcard/Wallpaper/");
// have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
nameofDirectory.mkdirs();
// create a File object for the output file
File outputFile = new File(nameofDirectory, filename);
// now attach the OutputStream to the file object, instead of a String representation
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
```

don't forget to put permission in android manifest