# How to store.csv file to a custom location on public internal drive (FileOutputStream)

Tags: android, android-activity, fileoutputstream

I would like to know if someone can assist me with the problem in saving the file to custom location. The purpose of the application is to store data in the csv when the button is pressed, which can be later transferred to the computer from internal disk on Android phone from the specific location (for Excel review and further manipulation). Code currently stores it into private application folder which can not be accessed:

```
    public void saveLogOnClick(View view) {
    //Name of the file created
    String FILENAME = "happy_log.csv";

    //Obrain the current text in the files convert it to string and save it to .csv file
    String entry = edtDate.getText().toString() + "," + edtTime.getText().toString() + "," +
            happyScore.getText().toString() + "," + normalScore.getText().toString() + "," +
            sadScore.getText().toString() + "\n";

    //Open a file with the streamer/pointer
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
        out.write(entry.getBytes());
        out.close();
        toastIt("Entry saved");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Edit: 
Now it works to the part where the new folder is created in public Directory Download, and also the csv file in the custom directory. However everytime when the method saveLogOnClick is initiated, does not append new information to the .csv, however just saves the latest one.

```
    String FILENAME = "happy_log.csv";
    //Obrain the current text in the files convert it to string and save it to .csv file
    String entry = edtDate.getText().toString() + "," + edtTime.getText().toString() + "," +
            happyScore.getText().toString() + "," + normalScore.getText().toString() + "," +
            sadScore.getText().toString() + "\n";
    //Open a file with the streamer/pointer
    try {
        File directoryDownload = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        File logDir = new File (directoryDownload, "Happy App Logs"); //Creates a new folder in DOWNLOAD directory
        logDir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(logDir, FILENAME);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        out.write(entry.getBytes()); //Write the obtained string to csv
        out.close();
        toastIt("Entry saved");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Animus

Answer (score 0):

First, in `AndroidManifest.xml` you have to request permission to write to external storage (ie outside of the app's sandbox)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then you can read/write in "/sdcard/", so for example

```
String FILENAME = "/sdcard/happy_log.csv";
```

will be accessible both to your app, and to your PC.

EDIT:

You can make directories like this

```
File picDirectory = new File("/sdcard/myFolder");
picDirectory.mkdirs();
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280176/make-directory-in-android)

EDIT2:

I don't know how openFileOutput() works because I've never used it, but I do the following:

```
File outfile = new File(getResources().getString(R.string.default_file_location)); // which is a string like "/sdcard/file.csv"
BufferedWriter bw = null;
try {
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outfile, true));
    bw.append(matchNum + ",");
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
} catch (IOException e) {

}
```

Comment: What about if I want that application stores the file to custom folder or to download folder on public internal storage?

Comment: This is a bit confusing, but "/sdcard/" is actually the internal storage, the physical, removable card is at "/sdcard/external_sd/".

Comment: I got this error:
09-05 20:51:26.203    5089-5089/com.sportelitemanagement.animus.happyapp W/System.err﹕ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /sdcard/happy_log.csv contains a path separator
09-05 20:51:26.203    5089-5089/com.sportelitemanagement.animus.happyapp W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:2049)
09-05 20:51:26.203    5089-5089/com.sportelitemanagement.animus.happyapp W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileOutput(ContextImpl.java:751)

Comment: And the actual java error is on 
W/System.err﹕ at com.sportelitemanagement.animus.happyapp.checkStats.saveLogOnClick(checkStats.java:113)
which is in my first post in TRY brackets

Comment: FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);

Comment: There was something mentioned also regarding : String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(); to put it before it actually creates a new dir

Comment: No everything works like a charm, except the new information saved does not add up, but replaces the previous information. Any help on that?

Comment: Hmm, that sounds like a "write mode" vs "append mode" thing. Check how you're opening the file, and how you're writing strings to it, use "append" options where available.

Comment: But is it so that I have to make two fileOutputStreams or how it is?

Comment: What? No. The definition is `FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)`....so make sure you create it as `FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file, true);`