# Making Directory In Android Studio

Tags: android

I am having trouble with creating a directory with android studio on my app. The problem is that my code is simply not creating a directory, but I can't seem to tell what the problem is. Here's my code:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/folder");
folder.mkdir();
```

I have also edited my manifests file to add this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also, I have no duplicates of the folder either.

Help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: "my code is simply not creating a directory" -- how are you determining this? If the answer is anything other than `adb shell ls`, bear in mind that the directory may not show up until you put a file in it and [get that file indexed by the `MediaStore`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl).

Comment: I am using this code:         boolean result = folder.mkdirs();
        Log.d("Directory made:" + result);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create a folder in android External Storage Directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781213/how-to-create-a-folder-in-android-external-storage-directory)

Comment: No, I have no duplicates

Comment: First, `mkdir()` will return `false` if the directory is already there. Beyond that, replace `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/folder")` with `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "folder")`, add [runtime permission support](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), and use `adb shell` to determine if your directory is actually there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"images");
directory.mkdirs();
```

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5280192/6759926)

Comment: Thank you! That helped fixed it along with some minor changes!