# barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.5 - How to pdfview.fromFile(). FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, pdf

I have tried a lot and tried all the soltution posted on Stackoverflow and other forums but with no luck. Every possible way gave me FieNotFoundException with either Bad Path or Wrong Path.

```
File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/download/my-pdf-file.pdf");
    pdfView.fromFile(pdfFile).load();
```

This is how I am trying to open the file from **Download** folder.
Note:

1. I am able to load the file from **Assets**  folder successfully.
2. I am using Pixel 2 API R as Android Emulator.
3. I have set permissions as

   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

This may help in asnwering.

```
2020-09-08 07:48:01.503 14928-14928/com.example.roohanikhazainp01 E/PDFView: load pdf error
java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:344)
    at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:231)
    at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.source.FileSource.createDocument(FileSource.java:37)
    at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:49)
    at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:25)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

I think there is something I am missing. Please help thanks

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221133/discussion-on-question-by-mindroastermir-bartekscandroid-pdf-viewer3-0-0-beta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was using API 29, 30 it is not possible anymore to access the external storage using

```
acceEnvironment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

so I have to give user an option to open the PDF from external drive using this.

```
Intent intentOpenPdf = new Intent((Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT));
intentOpenPdf.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intentOpenPdf.setType("application/pdf");
intentOpenPdf.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, myBookPath);
startActivityForResult(intentOpenPdf, 786);
```

And then in the function onActivityResult(). get the Uri to the selected pdf file like this.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (requestCode == 786 && data != null) {
        myPdfUri = data.getData();
        pdfView.fromUri(myPdfUri).load();
    }
}
```

Note: You can also save this Uri so that the use have not to select the PDF every time.

I used this approach.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (requestCode == 786 && data != null) {
       //Get the uri from data sent by Intent
        myPdfUri = data.getData();

       //Save the received uri for later use
       SharedPreferences sp = this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
       editor.commit();
       getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(myPdfUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        // Load the PDF using FromUri
        pdfView.fromUri(myPdfUri).load();
    }
}
```

Then at the beginning you can check if the uri is saved like this.

```
List<UriPermission> permissions = getContentResolver().getPersistedUriPermissions();
       if(permissions.isEmpty())
        {
            openPDF(myBookPath);
        }else{
            try {
                SharedPreferences sp2 = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                String myPdfUriString = sp2.getString("myPdfUri",""); // default is return if "myPdfUri" does not exist
                myPdfUri = Uri.parse(myPdfUriString);
                loadPdfView(null, myPdfUri, "");
            }catch (RuntimeException ex){
                Helper.Toaster(this, "Error : " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

This is working for me. Thanks